# Deleted Page Still In WordPress Database

Tags: database, wordpress

So I want my blog page to show up in the permalink URL as "blog" but apparently I've already created a page named "blog" at some point and deleted it. So the url in the permalinks becomes blog-2 and won't let me change it.

Does anyone know how to get rid of the old blog page so I can name the new one /blog in the permalinks?

Comment: Did you delete the page permanently? http://en.support.wordpress.com/trash/

Comment: Hi Dave.  I was just wondering if you got this to work?

Answer (score 1):

When you deleted your page, did you move it to the Trash?  If so, it may still be in your in there.  Try emptying your trash and then see you can use the /blog URL without any suffix.